# Rewrite rules for lighttpd with new document-root would not work

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd, document-root

I have

```
server.document-root = "/srv/www"
```

but for some static files I want use another document-root. I try use this code:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/hg/static" {
    url.rewrite-once = ("^/hg/static" => "/")
    server.document-root = "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/templates/static/"
}
```

but I get error in *error.log*:

```
2011-10-13 12:00:16: (/response.c.539) -- file not found 
2011-10-13 12:00:16: (/response.c.540) Path : /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/templates/static/hg/static/style-coal.css
```

when try:

```
  $ wget http://localhost/hg/static/style-coal.css
```

Real path to requested file is */usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/templates/static/style-coal.css* but server try locate */usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/templates/static/**hg/static/**style-coal.css*

Answer (score 2):

I use alias to resolve this problem:

```
alias.url = ( "/hg/static" => "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/templates/static/" )
```

but still don't understand how archieve this with mod_rewrite...